# Inject the OpenTracing's SpanContext in a Spring RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, opentracing, jaeger

I have the necessity to manually inject a `SpanContext` into a Spring `RestTemplate`.

For reasons that are irrelevant to the question, I can't just use "opentracing-spring-web-starter" because that would conflict with other starters I have set up and makes the project crash.

I have found this snippet of code relative to injecting the Context into an HTTP request, but I can't find anything relative to the a `RestTemplate`:

```
Tags.SPAN_KIND.set(tracer.activeSpan(), Tags.SPAN_KIND_CLIENT);
Tags.HTTP_METHOD.set(tracer.activeSpan(), "GET");
Tags.HTTP_URL.set(tracer.activeSpan(), url.toString());
tracer.inject(tracer.activeSpan().context(), Format.Builtin.HTTP_HEADERS, new RequestBuilderCarrier(requestBuilder));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the code in the `java-spring-web` library:

```java
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest httpRequest, byte[] body,
                                        ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        ClientHttpResponse httpResponse;

        Span span = tracer.buildSpan(httpRequest.getMethod().toString())
                .withTag(Tags.SPAN_KIND.getKey(), Tags.SPAN_KIND_CLIENT)
                .start();
        tracer.inject(span.context(), Format.Builtin.HTTP_HEADERS,
                new HttpHeadersCarrier(httpRequest.getHeaders()));
        ...
    }
```

Refs:

- [TracingRestTemplateInterceptor](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-web/blob/5262c01c5223ff2931685b9b572ce869b0c5caa8/opentracing-spring-web/src/main/java/io/opentracing/contrib/spring/web/client/TracingRestTemplateInterceptor.java#L74)
- [HttpHeadersCarrier](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-web/blob/5262c01c5223ff2931685b9b572ce869b0c5caa8/opentracing-spring-web/src/main/java/io/opentracing/contrib/spring/web/client/HttpHeadersCarrier.java#L25)